# Empty Filter Option display even no empty value exist

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter

Empty Filter Option is showing in Person or Group column even when there is no empty value existing in the column. Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is no “(Empty)” filter value in column header filter if this column does not have any empty value in the current view.

If you filter by “Empty”, will you get item results?

Create a view and set the filter: show the items when People or Group column is not empty (see below). Check the filter of People or Group column in this view to see whether there is “(Empty)” filter.
[image]

Besides, clear the browser cache and re-open the list. Check whether it works.